# ELException - Property not found - JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf-2, el, facelets

Our application is running with JSF (MyFaces, Trinidad) 1.2 on WebSphere 8.5. We are upgrading it to JSF 2.1. I'm getting the below exception with JSF 2.1

JSPX Code: `#{loginBackingBean.switchSkin}`
Java Code: `public String switchSkin() {...}` - This is a method.

> Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /header.jspx: Property 'switchSkin' not found on type com.LoginBackingBean
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:55)
>       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
>
> 000001ba ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause faces: javax.servlet.ServletException: /header.jspx: Property 'switchSkin' not found on type com.LoginBackingBean
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)

**Note:** Same exception is **NOT** occurring with JSF 1.2 and 2.0. 
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you upgrade Trinidad to a JSF 2.x compatible version?

Comment: And how/where is/should this be called?

Comment: @Kukeltje: stack tells that a plain XML/HTML element attribute is being written like so `<xxx attr="#{bean.action}">`. If `<xxx>` is supposed to be a JSF component, this in turn suggests it isn't being recognized as such. Given that OP is using JSPX and JSF 2.0 started to treat them the same way as Facelets, and the OP migrated from JSF 1.x, this in turn suggests OP didn't use a JSF 2.0 / Facelets compatible tag library but only a JSF 1.x / JSP one. The solution would be to either upgrade that component library to a JSF 2.x compatible one, or to downgrade the view technology from JSPX to JSP.

Comment: Could very wel be. Not used jsf1 for a long time. But I'd like to see the code. I had a similar error when for a strange reason PrimeFaces was not fully/correctly deployed. What normally should have been an action to be called was,by facelets, interpreted as a getter

Comment: @BalusC Sorry for the delayed response. I've updated the Facelets from 1.X to 2.X but I haven't updated the XMLNS and due to this, I got those errors. I solved the problem by correcting XMLNS for jstl. Thanks a lot.

`http://java.sun.com/jstl/core`

to:

`http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`

Comment: That indeed confirms my observation. JSTL tags weren't parsed and were interpreted as plain text, including all their attribtues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the Facelets from 1.X to 2.X but I haven't updated the XMLNS and due to this I got those errors. I solved the problem by correcting XMLNS for jstl. 
 `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` 
to: 
`http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`